# Is it possible to run a Mattermost instance as an onion service?

Tags: tor, mattermost

All is in the title: do you know if it's possible to deploy and use a Mattermost instance *via* Tor? Moreover, if I install Orbot on my Android phone, will I be able to connect to this instance *via* a Mattermost client? Thank you!

Comment: Your question interested me.
So I started some research on the subject. - It's interesting to see the official documentation: *https://docs.mattermost.com/install/requirements.html*.
We see the connection to the Mattermost server is down throwing an HTTP(s) request. - How to set up an onion service:
*https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/tor-onion-service.html.en* It's could be very teaching-full if you did this and upload how you did that. Have a good day!

Comment: Sorry, I have not tried yet, but thank you for your answer!